# Change Tiling size in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, tiling-wm

Is it possible to change the tiling size of windows (by moving them to the right or left edge of the monitor) in gnome 3?
Usually the left and the right window are each 50% wide but I'd like to make it 70/30

Answer (score 0):

Customizing Gnome 3  is  something between hard and impossible, as this "distracts the user" and damages the unique "Gnome brand identity".
Maybe one of the dozens of "extensions" will solve your problem, but even if such an extension does exist, there is no warranty that it will work with your version of Gnome 3.x, as the gnome devs intentionally break extension compatibility with every minor version change of Gnome 3.
J.